# Vertex weight Edit modifier not working as expected

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-groups

I wanted to have the vertex weight edit modifier driving through texture, but I have no idea why it's not working as expected I'm watching a tutorial and following the steps exactly but not getting the same results.

So I have a plane that I subdivided and created a new vertex group in it that's empty:

[image: Vertex group added - weight 0]

And then I added the modifier and I allowed group adding and chose my vertex group.
When I press invert falloff it works as expected (goes red)

[image: Vertex weight edit modifier with vertex group selected]

You can see I added the texture, but here's what my screen looks like:

[image: Musgrave texture not driving changes on the mesh]

As you can see there's no change and I don't understand why.... Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue. Change the falloff type to custom and set the first point from 0 to 1 (so the all falloff becomes a straight line on the top). Make sure that your vertex group is empty and the weight set to 0. Here are the settings of the modifier: [image]